# Liferay multiple portlets running with same embedded neo4j db

Tags: spring, liferay, spring-data-neo4j

Using spring data neo4j in liferay portlets, Neo4j is locking itself when a portlet is using it, encounter exception like below

```
Unable to lock store [db.name], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store
```

Is there any way to run multiple portlets with same embedded neo4j db. Can i use **Neo4j HA**? Looks like Neo4j HA to going to deal with multi-servers, but i only  one server. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try including neo4j library files at portal level instead of using at portlet level ?
i.e. to place required .jar files in /lib/ext instead of inside WEB-INF of every portlet.

I'm not an expert in neo4j, but having good experience with liferay. Suggesting above solution from liferay point to ensure common place for all portlets.

Comment: Hi Haris, thanks for reply, i put neo4j jars under /webapps/ROOT/lib, and specified portal.dependency.jars in liferay-plugin-package.properties

Comment: Hi Haris, can you also take a look at [this thread](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/38030017), it's a alternative solution i'm trying.

Comment: portal.dependency.jars copies jar file from /webapps/ROOT/lib to WEB-INF/lib of portlet. So, it maintains different instance of class per portlet. So, please try to place the neo4j jars in <liferay-portal-tomcat>/lib/ext and remove the .jars from /webapps/ROOT/lib and remove the property portal.dependency.jars

Comment: I don't feel that's good approach to access bean from portlet A context in portlet B context. Instead you can place multiple portlets in same context. This means more than one portlet <portlet> configuration can be placed in portlet.xml & liferay-portlet.xml Having this more than one portlet stay in same .war file

Comment: Hi Haris, we have 40+ porlets, is it a good practice to add so many portlets in one portlet.xml. If so, then my problem solved, but problem is these portlets are already there, and we don't want to keep so many portlets in one war.

Comment: Oh.. 40 is good number. Technically its feasible to include. But practically even I won't recommend more than 10 from manageability point. In this kind of scenario, my recommendation is to use service builder. This can be used even to generate classes in liferay way not just for database table mapping.Are you familiar with service builder ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54100/discussion-between-haris-and-zizibj).

Comment: I also try to create a portlet which do nothing but generate service layer, i create a service.xml with empty entity, run build-service so i get all service files, add my spring config in ext-spring.xml, try to inject my neo4j service bean to *LocalServiceImpl, i can get the bean in *LocalServiceImpl, but the dependencies in this service bean is not auto wired. i'm using spring auto-scan in ext-spring.xml. See my [configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/multi/setup.html#d0e3324) in ext-spring.xml